# Search and filter onedrive request

Tags: azure, filter, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am trying to search for only folders with specific name, so I am using search and filter parameters. According to [this search docs](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/blob/master/items/search.md) the search query should look like this:

`GET /drive/root/search(q='vacation')`

But if I want to add filter then according to [this filter docs](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/blob/master/odata/filtering.md) I should add `filter=folder ne null` but problem is how do I add It to original string ? In filter docs there is example of request

`GET /drive/root/search?q=vacation&filter=image%20ne%20null%20and%20file%20ne%20null`

which uses different syntax then example from search docs, and If I try to change It to my use like this

`GET /drive/root/search?q=folderName&filter=folder ne null` then I get 400 bad request reponse. So how can I search for specific item that is only folder ? thanks.

Comment: Are you making a call against OneDrive for consumer or business?

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could comment, all you need to do is UrlEncode your parameters, quoting from the search doc.

> Note: Samples omit proper URL encoding for readability. Actual filter syntax usage must be URL encoded.

For `filter=folder ne null`

This is what you should do append to url

```
filter%3Dfolder+ne+null
```